# Sitecore 10.2 Docker Deploy exits with Named Pipes Error

Tags: docker

I have recently installed Docker Desktop for Windows, version 20.10.10.
It is running in Windows Container mode.
I am running Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2.

I am going through the Sitecore XP 10.2.0 Developer Workstation Deployment With Docker as per this [this guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/5063B525E0AA46C6885C4EA211467C08.ashx?date=20210920T190029).
I have downloaded the [Sitecore 10.2 Container Deployment Package](https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/releases/tag/sxp%2F10.1.0.005207.309).

I have chose the ltsc2019 version of Windows, and XP0 topology.

I have successfully run the `composer-init.ps1` script.

However, when I run `docker-compose.exe up --detach`, once the downloads are complete I receive the following error:

```
[+] Running 11/11
 - Network sitecore-xp0_default                     Created                                                        0.5s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-mssql-1                   Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-solr-1                    Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-mssql-init-1              Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-solr-init-1               Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-id-1                      Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-xconnect-1                Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-xdbautomationworker-1     Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-xdbsearchworker-1         Created                                                        0.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-cortexprocessingworker-1  Created                                                        0.2s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-cm-1                      Created                                                        0.2s
 - Container sitecore-xp0-traefik-1                 Creating                                                       0.1s
Error response from daemon: Unrecognised volume spec: file '\\.\pipe\docker_engine' cannot be mapped. Only directories can be mapped on this platform
```

This seems to be related to this section of the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
    target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
    type: npipe
  - ./traefik:C:/etc/traefik
```

As a result, I am unable to start all of the Sitecore Containers. I would appreciate some direction on how to resolve this. I haven't been able to find much information on this error.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your Docker is running in Windows mode.

Comment: Try changing source and target of volumes like this: `source: '\\.\pipe\docker_engine\'`. Add trailing slash and wrap with single quotes

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
@MarekMusielak I tried wrapping in single quotes, still had the same error. I've also tried from Powershell, console and bash in Administrator mode.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I am running in Windows mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running in Docker Compose V2 mode. Run the following command:

`docker-compose disable-v2`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010612/error-response-from-daemon-unrecognised-volume-spec-file-pipe-docker-engi/70039471

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

After disabling the V2 mode `docker-compose disable-v2` You might still get the same error, you run the following docker-compose command which will remove the cache and execute. which was helped for me!

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and the solutions for me was to add a \ to the end.

So:

```
- source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine\
  target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine\
```

instead of:

```
- source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
  target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
```

Hope this helps someone.